# Run a TestNG test instance

Tags: java, testing, testng

I would like to run programmatically an instance of TestNG test. 
My test is like this:

```
public class MyTest {
    private Browser browser;
    private User user;

    public MyTest(Browser browser, User user) {
        this.browser = browser;
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Test public void testExample() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Since my test requires some objects to be passed to it's constructor to work I can't simply provide the test class object. So this won't work:

```
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(MyTest.class);
testng.run();
```

Any ideas on how can I do it with TestNG?

Comment: is there a reason why you are not doing this is Eclipse or in Ant? For these cases you have help on http://testng.org/doc/index.html

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by doing this in Eclipse or Ant. However, keep in mind that the objects that I need to pass as parameters to this test are a result of a previous calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a stactic variable or method to get those objects. But that only works if you dont plan on parallel execution of your tests.

```
public class ExampleClass{

private static Browser browser;

public DriverContainer(Browser brows){
    browser = brows;
}

public static Browser getBrowser() {
    return browser;
}
```

ExampleClass could be createdin another test class in an @BeforeSuite or @BeforeTest method.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

- Use a @Factory to create your objects.
- Use [TestNG's Guice support](http://beust.com/weblog/2010/12/10/testng-and-guice-a-marriage-made-in-heaven/) (the @Guice annotation) to inject the Browser and User objects.

You can actually both these approaches together.